# How I can add a IP field in contact form email magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, contact-form

How I can add a IP field in contact form email?
I added this field 
`{{var data.remoteAddress}}` to the email template

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table class="message-details">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Name"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Email"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "Phone"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "IP"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.remoteAddress}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="rtl"><strong>{{trans "Message"}}</strong></p>
<p class="rtl">{{var data.comment}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

and I edited this file: /public_html/vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright ֲ© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Contact\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var $remoteAddress
     */
    private $remoteAddress;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param MailInterface $mail
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $contactsConfig);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();

    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        try {
            $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');
    }

    /**
     * @param array $post Post data from contact form
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($post)
    {
        $this->mail->send(
            $post['email'],
            ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function validatedParams()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (trim($request->getParam('name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Name and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('comment')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the comment and try again.'));
        }
        if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('hideit')) !== '') {
            throw new \Exception();
        }

        return $request->getParams();
    }
}
```

But still the IP field that is received in the email is empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this code working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the `remoteAddress` variable to the array returned by the `validatedParams()` function.

Possibly, change the line

```php
    return $request->getParams();
```

to

```php
    // Add a remote address attribute
    $params = $request->getParams();
    $params['remoteAddress'] = $this->remoteAddress;
    return $params();
```

and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

In the contact us form if you add hidden IP form field in template logic with ID and name as `ip` and populate it with IP adress using php all you then need to do is overwrite the contact us email template

etc/email_templates.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_attachment_email_template" label="Contact Form with IP" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Extension" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/email/submitted_form.html

```html
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{{trans "IP"}}</strong></td>
        <td>{{var data.ip}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Ref

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment/blob/master/etc/email_templates.xml

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml